# Is there a kind of certificate for those who have listened to a lot of music?

Tags: music-business

There are certificates for those who can play musical instruments. Is there a certificate for those who have listened to a lot of music?

Comment: Can you detail your question? What do you mean "for those who have listened to a lot of music"?

Comment: How would you even quantify or verify this? And why, what good is having "listened to a lot of music" if it hasn't resulted in some other testable skill?

Comment: You could make one for yourself at a site like this:  https://certificatemagic.com/

Comment: @mlibby Thank you! I didn't know there are services like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a course in music appreciation you'll probably get some kind of certificate of participation. That's probably the closest you'll get to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that should be.